# Setting "HorizontalContentAlignment" to stretch within ItemcontainerStyle of list view is not stretching beyond the view port

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

In the following XAML and XAML.cs, I've the listview item's horizontal content alignment to stretch. But, what I observe is, it is stretching fine only when the content is within the view port. If the content exceeds the view port and when horizontal scroll viewer is visible, the items are not stretching any further

Any thoughts on why is this happening and any resolution? I've attached a screenshot of the same below

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView SelectionMode="Single" x:Name="TestView"  Grid.Row="1"                             
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"  
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"  
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"                  
                  ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind strList}">
            <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection/>
            </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#F0F0F0"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                                     />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <!--  END-->
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

**XAML.cs (For testing purposes)**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
 private List<string> strList = new List<string>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            for(int i=1;i<50;i++)
            {
                if (i == 1)
                    strList.Add(i.ToString() + " sdffsdfsdfsd sdf sdfsdf sdfdsf sdfdsf sfsd fsd sdfsdf sdfsdf  dsfsdf sfdsf sdfdsf sdfsdsf sdfdsfsd sdffsdfsdfsd sdf sdfsdf sdfdsf sdfdsf sfsd fsd sdfsdf sdfsdf  dsfsdf sfdsf sdfdsf sdfsdsf sdfdsfsd sdffsdfsdfsd sdf sdfsdf sdfdsf sdfdsf sfsd fsd sdfsdf sdfsdf  dsfsdf sfdsf sdfdsf sdfsdsf sdfdsfsd sdffsdfsdfsd sdf sdfsdf sdfdsf sdfdsf sfsd fsd sdfsdf sdfsdf  dsfsdf sfdsf sdfdsf sdfsdsf sdfdsfsd sdffsdfsdfsd sdf sdfsdf sdfdsf sdfdsf sfsd fsd sdfsdf sdfsdf  dsfsdf sfdsf sdfdsf sdfsdsf sdfdsfsd sdffsdfsdfsd sdf sdfsdf sdfdsf sdfdsf sfsd fsd sdfsdf sdfsdf  dsfsdf sfdsf sdfdsf sdfsdsf sdfdsfsd sdffsdfsdfsd sdf sdfsdf sdfdsf sdfdsf sfsd fsd sdfsdf sdfsdf  dsfsdf sfdsf sdfdsf sdfsdsf sdfdsfsd sdffsdfsdfsd sdf sdfsdf sdfdsf sdfdsf sfsd fsd sdfsdf sdfsdf  dsfsdf sfdsf sdfdsf sdfsdsf sdfdsfsd sdffsdfsdfsd sdf sdfsdf sdfdsf sdfdsf sfsd fsd sdfsdf sdfsdf  dsfsdf sfdsf sdfdsf sdfsdsf sdfdsfsd sdffsdfsdfsd sdf sdfsdf sdfdsf sdfdsf sfsd fsd sdfsdf sdfsdf  dsfsdf sfdsf sdfdsf sdfsdsf sdfdsfsd sdffsdfsdfsd sdf sdfsdf sdfdsf sdfdsf sfsd fsd sdfsdf sdfsdf  dsfsdf sfdsf sdfdsf sdfsdsf sdfdsfsd sdffsdfsdfsd sdf sdfsdf sdfdsf sdfdsf sfsd fsd sdfsdf sdfsdf  dsfsdf sfdsf sdfdsf sdfsdsf sdfdsfsd ");
                else
                    strList.Add(i.ToString());
            }
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide two solutions first:

1. Use `TextWrapping` or `TextTrimming` to limit the width of the **TextBlock** to no more than the visible area, like:

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

2. Use `ScrollViewer` as a container

```xml
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
         HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
         HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">

    <ListView SelectionMode="Single" x:Name="TestView"                              
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind strList}">
        ...
    </ListView>

</ScrollViewer>
```

Now let's talk about the reason.

The key is the **visible area**. Before the `ScrollViewer` is used, the visible area is only the window size. UWP is used as a reference when rendering.

After using the `ScrollViewer` as a container, the theoretical viewable area is infinite, and the UWP will render according to the width of the `ScrollViewer`, so that all the list items can be made to have the same width.

But at the same time, because the viewable area is infinite, `ListView` will load all the list items at once, so when the data set is large, it is not recommended to use `ScrollViewer` as the container of `ListView`.

Best regards.